# How to paste primary selection into Vim?

Tags: vim, clipboard, selection

I use the middle-click, or <kbd>CTRL-SHIFT-V</kbd> to paste indented selection into Vim:

```
<a>
    <b>
    <c>
</a>
```

I have tried to

```
:set nosmartindent
:set nosmarttab
```

It's used to working, but recently nosmartindent doesn't work any more. The result is something like:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
        </a>
```

*EDIT*

It seems like I should also disable the filetype:

```
set filetype=text
```

Then, things go right, no more indents again.

But, should I have to `set nosmart*, set filetype=text` each time before paste?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are not talking about `gvim`, but the console `vim`.

Your `vim` seems unaware that you are pasting and treats the pasted text as inserted as if typed. Try putting `vim` in `paste` mode:

```
:set paste
```

Once you are done pasting leave `paste` mode again:

```
:set nopaste
```

See [this entry](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip906) in the `vim` wiki for more information.